# Is there way to add fields in the Dynamic Forms and not show them while creating records

Tags: lightning-web-components, flexipages

I have upgraded my FlexiPage to Dynamic Forms but there are few fields that I want to show only on the record detail page and not on the new record page otherwise I will have to customized the new record page and then redirect it to the FlexiPage.

Comment: you have to customized the new record page and override the standard New button. At least I'm doing that to accomplish the same workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I also started doing that. Couldn't see any other option. But there are other challenges with that.